# Flutter - Padding on AppBar

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart

The app I'm developing must be in full screen mode at all times, however, the time/date must also be shown at all times, as well as a certain Hardware ID. We found the following way to present said information:

[image: Screenshot of the app with debug paint on]

However, as you may see above, I marked in red a Padding widget that is always above my AppBar, and we would like to remove that padding. Is such a thing possible?

Below I have the code for the custom AppBar we're using.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45),
  child: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(pageName,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: pageNameFontSize
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        )
      ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 6,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              AppBarClock(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(this.trailText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

We are using *SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);* to make the app full screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `AppBar` automatically includes a `SafeArea` whenever treated as primary.

Just set the `primary` property of it to `false`.

```
AppBar(
   primary: false,
   ...
)
```